# Create Forms in Drupal and process them

Tags: forms

i am new to Drupal and i want to implement training / seminar program in my Drupal site. I want to know how to implement the following features:

1. The administrator will be creating a seminar / training session program from a form in admin panel, with details like name, date and description. How to add a form in admin panel and save its details in a new table in database ? Do i need to create a module here?
2. The training sessions and seminars created by admin can be viewed by the users in the front end with a scrollbar div block. How to show this information in front end ?
3. When they click on the name of a program in the block, it will lead to a separate screen, where the user can view the program details (name, date and description) and a button to register... how to create a new screen in drupal?
4. When the user clicks on register button, he will be enrolled in the program (saved in database with inactive status). Now the admin must be able to view the programs he created, in admin panel, and when he clicks on a program name, the registered users in that program will appear. Then he can click on a user's name and a small screen to 'Accept' him in the program and save his status to 1 in the database. How to implement this ?

Basically i want to know how to create forms in Drupal and how can i show them in the front end. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Basically, i just want to know how can i create forms for the administrator.

Comment: @dskanth Then you also need to look at http://drupal.org/project/acl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using Drupal7.  I will provide some pointers but you'll have to look up the details on your own.

1. Sounds like you might want to create a new Content Type.
2. [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) can generate a list of a specific Content Type (in your case, list only seminars).
3. [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) typically links each item in the list to the actual node with the full info
4. The [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) module will allow you to create sign up forms but there's likely more that you'll have to do to tie everything together.

Comment: Thanks for the info... i am searching for the ways to create form in the admin panel and save its details in the database, and then show the list in the front end. How to go about it ?